# What does this OpenCL code mean? How does uchar16 work? (OpenCV laplacian3.cl source)

Tags: opencv, opencl

In https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/imgproc/src/opencl/laplacian3.cl, line 107-118, I found the following code:

```
    arr[0] = (uchar16)(a, b.s0123, b.s456789ab, b.scde);
    arr[1] = b;
    arr[2] = (uchar16)(b.s123, b.s4567, b.s89abcdef, c);
    arr[3] = (uchar16)(d, e.s0123, e.s456789ab, e.scde);
    arr[4] = e;
    arr[5] = (uchar16)(e.s123, e.s4567, e.s89abcdef, f);
    arr[6] = (uchar16)(g, h.s0123, h.s456789ab, h.scde);
    arr[7] = h;
    arr[8] = (uchar16)(h.s123, h.s4567, h.s89abcdef, i);
    arr[9] = (uchar16)(j, k.s0123, k.s456789ab, k.scde);
    arr[10] = k;
    arr[11] = (uchar16)(k.s123, k.s4567, k.s89abcdef, l);
```

The variables `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l` are declared as following:

```
    uchar a; uchar16 b; uchar c;
    uchar d; uchar16 e; uchar f;
    uchar g; uchar16 h; uchar i;
    uchar j; uchar16 k; uchar l;
```

I'm a little confused what does, for example, `b.s0123` do? It doesn't look like normal C++ code to me. Maybe it's special OpenCL grammar?

Comment: The file is not C++. It is OpenCL. The `(uchar16)(/*..*/)` syntax is not valid in C++. In C++ `s0123` would just be a normal identifier.

Comment: Correction: `(uchar16)(a, b.s0123, b.s456789ab, b.scde)` is valid syntax, but unlikely to be semantically useful in C++. `,` would be the comma operator that will discard all but the right-most operand, unless `operator,` is overloaded for the types of the involved expressions.

Comment: @reelsun I've removed the C++ tag. you should be very careful with that tag. it attracts "direct" people that can tell you a lot about C++, even when that's not _your_ problem, which is not knowing what OpenCL is. please do learn about OpenCL.

Comment: https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the advice. I indeed have looked up tutorials and API documents for OpenCL, and skimmed through the webpage you posted. The problem is that I cannot find anything obviously relevant to my question on this page. Even now that I know what's going on, I still cannot find a section that describes it as good as your answer.

Comment: yeah sadly the official docs are lousy. lots of docs for APIs out there are lousy. I think I learned what little I know of it from university-level courses (also slide sets on the internet). a bunch of OpenGL knowledge (kernels/shaders) is transferable. the same nutjobs cooked up both technologies. they're also lousy at naming things clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenCL, an `uchar16` is a 16-element vector.

You can access its elements using a kind of "member" syntax. You can access individual elements (`b.s0`), or access several elements as another vector (`b.s0123`).

Given that `b` is an `uchar16`...

```
arr[0] = (uchar16)(a, b.s0123, b.s456789ab, b.scde);
```

That composes a *new* uchar16 (and assigns it to `arr[0]`), using the value of `a` and the first 15 elements of `b` (`0` to `e`), accessed in three pieces: two 4-element and one 3-element vector. The values of `b` appear *shifted* to the right (the view is shifted left).

```
arr[1] = b;
```

That just copies the vector.

```
arr[2] = (uchar16)(b.s123, b.s4567, b.s89abcdef, c);
```

That's like the first case, except now the *last* 15 values of `b` are taken, along with `c`. This makes `b` appear shifted to the *left* now.

That pattern repeats another three times, with different variables.

Overall, that looks like a convolution is set up by preparing a (big) matrix. I'm guessing it's a 3x3 convolution (the shifts) and it can operate on 4-channel data (`b,e,h,k`).

That makes sense because the laplacian is calculated as a convolution of a kernel.

You are not gonna learn much about the laplacian or convolutions from *those implementations*. These implementations are *code*. Code does not explain the theory.

Comment: Thanks! I know what Laplacian is and I'm trying to implement my own C++ version for a project. I'm trying to learn from the OpenCV implementation because that's the only version I found that supports a kernel bigger than 3.

Comment: laplacian is "separable". look that up if you don't know it yet. it's also symmetric, so in a pass, you can get away with half the multiplications: `(im[+k] + im[-k]) * w[k]`

Comment: One thing still remain a little confusing to me is that, for example, in```arr[0] = (uchar16)(a, b.s0123, b.s456789ab, b.scde);```, ```a``` is of uchar type, what does it mean to combine its value with the 15 elements of ```b```? Is the first or last element of ```a``` used?

Comment: just `uchar` means it's scalar, not a vector. by "combine" I mean use it in the construction of a new uchar16.